# How to pass a 'using namespace' to start-threadjob that is calling a function?

Tags: powershell

**Question:**

I have a function being called with Start-ThreadJob and that function needs the following namespace to work with it:

```
     using namespace System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader
```

How do I get this to be seen by the function ?

**Deeper Dive:**

The code is a little complex but I generate a queued list of objects that are used to spawn off a thread, the function name is the tag and that is the actual function being called. My issue is that the code doesn't recognize the namespace declared at the top of the script so I believe it has to be passed to the function thread somehow?

**Code Sample (a little complex):**

```
     Function MyFunctionName { Write-Host("Hello World") }

     $Queue += [pscustomobject]@{
        Tag = 'MyFunctionName'  # Function to Invoke here
     }

    $commandDefinitions = @{}
    $WorkerJobs = foreach ($Task in $Queue) {
        # If we already have the Definition for this Action
        if ($commandDefinitions.ContainsKey($Task.Tag)) {
            $def = $commandDefinitions[$Task.Tag]  # use it
        }
        else {
            # else, get it and set it
            $def = (Get-Command $Task.Tag -CommandType Function).Definition
            $commandDefinitions[$Task.Tag] = $def
        }
        
        Start-ThreadJob { 
            & ([scriptblock]::Create($using:def)) @Using:Task 
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is, you shouldn't because the solution is not pretty nor very reliable. You should use the types fully qualified name instead inside the thread's script block. For the sake of demonstration here is how you can do it:

```
$usingStatements = @'
using namespace System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
'@

function Test {
    [EventLogReader]
    [EventLogQuery]
    [List[object]]
}

$func = ${function:Test}.ToString()

Start-ThreadJob {
    . ([scriptblock]::Create($using:usingStatements))

    ${function:Test} = $using:func

    Test
} | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

Comment: THANKS! I was going for calling the functions from a queue, should I just get away from that for this as I do not see a way to call the $def like I did before ?

Comment: @MikeQ oh you can still use the same method you are using in your question without problems but you need to use the scriptblock invoking the using statements before it

Comment: Thanks that worked..  by just adding it in beforehand. The speed got a bit better, I think I need to try to figure out how to filter a bit more on my 'api' calls